# JSON Path Extractor in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am new to jmeter. Can anyone help me to use a response object of one request to be passed as a request header of next HTTP request ?

Let me explain.

1. I am getting an access token along with the response of login in my app:

   {:   "responseCode":18, :   "message":"Successfully logged in.", :   "responseObject":"8zWExE4eSdhcJDwnW9MgIw=="}
2. No I want to use this access token (8zWExE4eSdhcJDwnW9MgIw) as one of the parameter of next request.

I used JSON Path Extractor for this.But its not working.

Comment: But I have already tried using $.responseObject and $.responseObject[0] and its not working. 
Lemme explain what I have tried in this scenario.

Comment: These are the components i have implemented in my test script.
1 HTTP Request Defaults
2 HTTP Cookie Manager
3. User Defined Variables
    (Inside this a variable is declared as "access_Token" and its value as "jsonVal", which is the JSON Path Extractor Name)
4. HTTP Request (Login)
   (This request is giving the response as
     {
:       "responseCode":18,
:       "message":"Successfully logged in.",
:       "responseObject":"NXVQR/bQBGJV4ugJOgpQeg=="
     }
   )
4.1 HTTP Header Manager
4.2 JSON Path Extractor
(Extractor name is jsonVal, which i have passed in User defined variables)

Comment: 5 HTTP Request (Reservation)
   its request body is like
{
"eventId":4446,
"buyerId":10,
"invCount":1,
"eventPriceId":169
}

5.1 HTTP Header Manager
      Accept         application/json
      Content-Type application/json
      accessToken ${access_Token}

6 Result Tree
Response of Reservation Request is 
{
:   "responseCode":100,
:   "message":"Invalid Access Token."
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using JSON Path Extractor as well and it works great if it is properly configured.
Just put it into request and fill fields:

- Variable Name: access_token (or any other you want to use later in request like this ${access_token})
- JSON Path: responseObject should be enough if the JSON you pasted is full response (thjose additional colons are just some mistakes when copy-pasting or the JSON is corrupted?)
- Default Value: I always use some value like 'NotUpdated!' here so I can assert in the next step or at least see it easily in request.

Comment: Hi,
I hope you can see the response which is giving me the accessToken. And i think that i have configured it correct. Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: I think that the problem can be you response with that responseObject, as there are some colons that shouldn't be there, unless it's just some strange formatting. I'm talking about that colon before responseObject name like here': "responseObject"', that is probably parsing that JSON wrongly.
I see one more thing, If the value you assign is "jsonVal", not ${jsonVal} then the problem can be here. Or it is assigned first and then extracted. Try to use in your next request ${jsonVal} and see if it is there.

Comment: I've read your comments one more time and just to add a bit - you don't have to assign that jsonVal to access_token, just use access_token name instead that jsonVal in extractor so you will have it assigned straight forward to not complicate it unnecessary.

Comment: No that colon is just in coming when i switch the view of response to json view in result tree from Text to JSON. Its not the part of the actual response. JMeter place those colon only at that point. Actual response will be like this. {"responseCode":18,"message":"Successfully logged in.","responseObject":"VhE/3ENBM9+METEQPLHI6Q=="}

Comment: And the case with using ${jsonVal} or jsonVal, do i need to try it with User defined variable?

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
accessToken: ${jsonVal}
Content-Length: 71
Host: 182.72.159.116:8080
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.6 (java 1.5)

Comment: That was it..I was unnecessarily complicating thinks. I used Json extractor name directly as the request header param and it worked.

Thanks you so much.

Comment: Always happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Not seeing the full response it is quote hard to come up with a correct JSON Path expression.

Given what you posted it should be something like `$.responseObject`

See [JSON Path Syntax](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2) guide for queries syntax examples and [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) (scroll down to "Parsing JSON") for plugin installation instructions and XPath to JSON syntax mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anybody would face an issue with multiple variable extractions using JSON Extractor (like me), make sure to:

- List the names of variables/path expressions/default values using a semicolon as a separator.
- Provide default values for every variable.

The second point is apparently required, and I only found out about it from [this](https://gvasanka.medium.com/extract-multiple-variables-with-jmeter-json-extractor-aec1e0e2b332)
Medium post.