# How to store a generated bearer token to a variable

Tags: jmeter

I'm testing some methods like sending a message, checking message status .. etc using Jemeter. To execute these methods I need a bearer / access token. I was able to generate a token, But I cannot figure out how to get that value stored in a variable and use in other post methods.
Can somebody help me with this?[Image of my tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wdpzy.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON Path Extractor in JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828549/json-path-extractor-in-jmeter)

Comment: Asked with answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828549/json-path-extractor-in-jmeter

Answer (score 2):

Use the Regular Expression Extractor:
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor
set reference: token
use regular expression: access_token":"([^"]+)"

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) (it is available since [JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30)), the relevant JSON Path query would be as simple as `$.access_token`

Demo:

[image: JSON Path Extractor Demo]

See [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#jayway-jsonpath) for more information on JSON Path language.

Comment: Hi Dimitri, Thanks for the answer. I also wonna know how to use this saved value in another method. If I add the Name: Authorization ,  value : Bearer $.access_token, this doesn't work. Under the view results, I get the response as "Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 401
Response message: Unauthorized"

Comment: 1. Define a "Reference Name" in the JSON Extractor, it may be anything meaningful, i.e. `token`
2. You will be able to refer the extracted value as `${token}` where required.